# Dart version in Android and Flutter engine is different

Tags: flutter, dart

My Flutter Engine using **Dart version 2.5** whereas the dart in the android studio seems to have **Dart 2.6.1.**

> Is that any potential issue while developing any project?

How can I ensure that both are same? How can I downgrade the version, please? 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36yzi.png)

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about that. Flutter will keep using its own Dart version.

The other one will be used when running Dart scripts from CLI.